use python libraries with cx_freeze
I am currently trying to convert a Python script into an .exe file. At first I put together a simple programme to find out how I can do this. I came across the library cx_freeze.
With this library I am able to convert a simple Python script into an .exe file. I am also able to integrate libraries such as os or subprocess without any problems.
However, I fail with the libraries Pandas, Matplotlib.pyplot and Matplotlib.tkinter. I get the following error:
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Can any of you give me a tip on how I can also integrate the libraries mentioned above?
Many thanks in advance!
Here is the code from the setup.py file:
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

setup(name="Test file", version="1.0", options = {'build_exe': {'packages': ['pandas', 'os', 'subprocess', 'matplotlib.pyplot', 'matplotlib.tkinter', 'glob', 'datetime']}}, description="Just a test file", executables=[Executable("Test_file.py")])


Avoid to directly list the packages, cx_freeze already does it: https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/stable/setup_script.html. Try this instead:
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
setup(
 name="Test file", 
 version="1.0", 
 description="Just a test file", 
 executables=[Executable("Test_file.py")]
)


Thanks for the quick reply!
This approach works as long as I don't work with Pandas, Numpy, Sympy or similar libraries...I quickly tested it with a simple programme.
As soon as I want to include Pandas I get the same error as before...
Do you have any other idea how I can solve this problem?

Could you provide a detailed stack trace to identify the issue ?

Sure!
Here is the error message I get on the console:
File "", line 1204, in _gcd_import
File "", line 1173, in _find_and_load
File "", line 170, in enter
File "", line 196, in _get_module_lock
File "", line 72, in init
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Okay, I have found out how to fix the problem. However, I'm not sure if this method is okay or not.
Therefore, I am glad for feedback.
I dragged the exclude sequence before the include sequence and first excluded the libraries that were causing problems and then included them again.
Is this allowed or should I not do this?

Well done. Yes its allowed but you should not to this. Only exclude should do the work since cx_freeze collects all the needed packages. How did you build the executable ? In a virtualenv ? Which Python version are you using ?
cx_freeze seems unable to load a parent module, perhaps matplotlib i guess. Check your sys.modules dict to see where it is located.

Okay. Thanks for the answer!
What are the consequences of doing this? I'm asking purely out of interest...
I work with Anaconda. I created the .exe file via the anaconda promt (with the appropriate commands for cx_Freeze).
I use the Python version 3.11.5
Yes, it seems to be due to the Matplotlib library...I was able to reduce the libraries I exclude and then include again to Matplotlib. So the problem seems to be there, as you suggest...
Okay. How do I find this sys.modules dict exactly?

No consequences. You can do it if its work but it's a bad practice to exclude and then include the same thing in a config file. Another programmer seeing your code could not understand.

To see the sys modules dict, just print it in a script. import sys print(sys.modules).

As i said if your fix works then dont speed too much time with this. I suggest you to test the same script in a virtual environment and see if you have the same issue. Perhaps the Anaconda environment is not well configured, i don't know. For Anaconda i can't help you.
